# Application of Dirichlet theorem and Dirchlet density

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, dirichlet-character

I'm reading Serre's A course in Arithmetic and I have the following question about Proposition 14 in Chapter VI. It uses this version of Dirichlet's theorem: Let $m\ge 1$, $(a,m) = 1$. Let $P_a$ be the set of prime numbers such that $p\equiv a \mod m$. The set $P_a$ has density $1/\phi(m)$.

**Proposition 14** Let $a$ be an integer which is not a square. The set of prime numbers $p$ such that $\bigl(\frac{a}{p}\bigr) = 1$ has density $\frac{1}{2}$.

His proof goes like this: **WLOG $a$ is square free.** Let $m=4|a|$ and $\chi_a$ be the unique character $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}^\times$ such that $\chi_a(p) = \bigl(\frac{a}{p}\bigr)$ for all prime numbers $p$ not dividing $m$. Note that $\bigl(\frac{a}{p}\bigr) = 1$ iff $p \in \ker\chi_a$. **Using Dirichlet's theorem, $[\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}^\times: \ker \chi_a]$ is equal to the density of the primes satisfying this condition. $\square$**

I have three questions about this:

1. Why can we assume a is square free?
2. How do we apply Dirichlet? In particular, we selected $m = 4|a|$ and $m$ is not coprime with $a$, so I'm not sure how the theorem is applied.
3. How is the index equal to the density of the primes satisifying the condition? (I don't quite understand the last sentence of the proof)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can you take $a$ squarefree: just look at an example, say $a = 45 = 3^2 \cdot 5$. The value of $(\frac{45}{p})$ equals the value of $(\frac{5}{p})$ as long as $p \not= 3$.

Since $\chi_a$ is a nontrivial quadratic character, it takes two values and those values are given by *congruence conditions*:  the kernel of $\chi_a$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z)^\times$ with index 2, so the kernel has size $\varphi(m)/2$. The primes in each unit class has density $1/\varphi(m)$, so the primes that reduce mod $m$ to a congruence class in $\ker \chi_a$ have density $(\varphi(m)/2))/\varphi(m) = 1/2$.

Comment: Thanks! So instead of the $a$ in the original proposition, we are actually taking $a$ to be every integer coprime to m when we are finding the density.

Comment: Break up the set you're interested in into congruence classes mod $m$ and sum the density of primes in each congruence class.  Try working through Serre's proof with an actual example, like $a = 6$ or $a = 15$.